# How to create table over partitioned data

Tags: hive

I have text file with snappy compression partitioned by field 'process_time' (result of Flume job). Example: `hdfs://data/mytable/process_time=25-04-2019`

This is my script for create table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable
(
... 
) 
PARTITIONED BY (process_time STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/data/mytable/'
TBLPROPERTIES("textfile.compress"="snappy");
```

The result of queries against this table are allways 0 (but I know that there are some data). Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you are `creating external table` on top of `HDFS directory` then to add the partitions to the hive table we need to run either of these commands.

- if any partition added to **HDFS directly**`(instead of using insert queries)` then **hive doesn't know** about the newly added partitions, so we need to run either `msck (or) add partitions` to add newly added partitions to hive table.

***`To add all partitions to hive table:`***

```
hive> msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>;
```

**(or)**

***`To manually add each partition to hive table:`***

```
hive> alter table <db_name>.<table_name> add partition(process_time="25-04-2019") 
      location '/data/mytable/process_time=25-04-2019';
```

For more details [refer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions) to this link.